# Type checking with an array in Typescript

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm attempting to call the api = https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type

I wish to display the array in the data using the async pipe.

I'm doing this via the html:

```
<option *ngFor="let pokemonType of pokemonTypes$ | async" [value]="pokemonType.url">{{pokemonType.name | titlecase}}</option>
```

I have a Filter interface for this:

```
export interface Filter {
  name: string;
  url: string;
}
```

I have the following method in my httpService file:

```
getTypes(): Observable<Filter[]> {
        return this.http.get<Filter[]>("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type", { responseType: 'json', observe: 'response' }).pipe(map((res: any) => res.body.results));
    }
```

But when I try to set `pokemonTypes$` in my component:

```
pokemonTypes$: Filter[] = [];
this.pokemonTypes$ = this.httpService.getTypes();
```

I get the following error:

```
Type 'Observable<Filter[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Filter[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 27 more
```

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @tony just tried that but didn't work. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: try `pokemonTypes$: Observable<Filter[]>`; instead of `pokemonTypes$: Filter[] = [];`

Comment: `this.httpService.getTypes();`  returns observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pokemonTypes$ is expected to be an observable, yet your'e initializing it as an empty list.

if you want to init it with empty list, you should init it as an observable which contains empty list like this:

```
pokemonTypes$ = of([]) as Observable<Filter[]>;
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that but now getting a new error = Type 'Observable<Filter[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<never[]>'.
  Type 'Filter[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
    Type 'Filter' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: then declare it's type: of([]) as Observable<Filter[]>

Comment: btw is there a way I can get rid of the any in res: any?

Comment: create an interface which describes your response object and get any replaced by it

Comment: Would that interface be for the "res" level or the "res.body.results" level?